# Information Management Policy on list to kick off workflow that sends a weekly summary email

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, information-management

I am using SP 2010. My assignment is to create a process that sends one weekly email for updates/additions to List A, instead of on each change. 
I created a workflow on list A. Any time there has been an addition/update I create a record in another list (List B). I then created a workflow on List B that sends an email.

At this point, I get a little confused. How can I set up the workflow to pick up new/ modified records for that particular week only and send summary of that information in one email?

I was looking into Information Management Policy kicking off my workflow on list B. I got the email piece working (I'm receiving email daily now). I must have set it up incorrectly because i'm getting an email for each item in the list. I need only one email with a summary of the items for that week.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying will not be easy using workflows.

The only posiblity I see is to create a new list with one item which has a Multiline text field.

The workflow on the list can then add information to that list item on each add/update (but not on deletes).

A second workflow which can either be at site level or on the dummy list, can the be set to wait the appropiate time, grap the content of the field, send mail, clear field.

**But why not just set up an alert on the list and select weekly summary???**